# Prove that the sequence $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}$ ($b_1=1$) contains infinitely many elements that are divisible by $7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Let the sequence $b_n$ such that $$b_1=1, \; b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]} \;\; \text{for all}\;\; n \ge 2,$$ where $\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]$ is an integer part of a real number $\frac{n}{2}$  ($\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]$ is a largest integer not exceeding $\frac{n}{2}$). 
>   Prove that the sequence $b_n$ contains infinitely many elements that are divisible by $7$.

**My work**. The sequence $b_n$ is 
$1, 2, 3, 5, \fbox{7}, 
10, 13, 18, 23, 30, 37, 47, 57, \fbox{70}, 
83, 101, \fbox{119}, 
142, 165, 195, 225, 262, 299, 346, 393, 450, 507, 577, 647, 730, 813, 914, \fbox{1015}, 
\fbox{1134}, 
\fbox{1253}, 
1395, 1537, 1702, 1867, 2062, 2257, 2482, 2707, 2969, 3231, 3530, \fbox{3829}, 
4175, 4521, \fbox{4914}, 
5307, 5757, 6207, 6714, 7221, \fbox{7798}, 
8375, 9022, 9669, 10399, 11129, \fbox{11942}, 
12755, 13669, 14583, 15598, 16613, 17747, 18881, 20134, 21387, 22782, 24177, 25714, \fbox{27251}, 
28953, 30655, \fbox{32522}, 
34389, 36451, 38513, 40770, 43027, 45509, 47991, 50698, 53405, 56374, 59343, 62574, 65805, \fbox{69335}, 
72865, 76694, 80523, 84698, 88873, \fbox{93394}, 
97915.$

It is not easy to see what is the pattern here.

Comment: That's http://oeis.org/A033485 (which might be helpful or not).

Comment: Apparently solved on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h243404p1339665 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24b_n%3Db_%7Bn-1%7D%2Bb_%7B%5Cleft%5B%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%5D%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First simplify to: $b_n=(b_{n-1}+b_{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}) \pmod 7$

Now the divisible by 7 test is just $=0$.

Observe that for each 0 that does occur, there is a sequence of three equal numbers.
To be specific, if $b_n$ is 0, then $b_{2n}$, $b_{2n+1}$ and $b_{2n+2}$ are all the same.
If those are 0 themselves, we have another match.

Observe that for each sequence of three equal non-zero numbers, we get a sequence of seven numbers in arithmetic progression (mod 7).
To be specific, if $b_n$ is 0, for $m \in [0,6]$ we get $b_{4n+m} = (b_{4n}+m\times{b_{2n}}) \pmod7 $.
One of them must be 0, so we have another match.

QED.

Comment: I didn't understand why we obtain a seven number arithmetic progression

Comment: I don't understand your proof. How to understand it "Observe that for each 0 that does occur, there is a sequence of three equal numbers" ?

Comment: This is simply the AoPS solution mentioned in MartinR's comment, poorly reworded. -1

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: independently derived, actually.  But, yes, it works out the same.  Actually, I started by trying to see if I could find a pattern.  I quickly hit integer overflow, so I did everything mod 7.  In the first 1,000,000 entries, 142,944 are divisible by 7.  In 10,000,000: 1,428,829.  In 100,000,000: 14,281,122.  The density seemed to be decreasing, and I was running out of memory.

Comment: my previous counts are wrong, and I rewrote to use logarithmic memory....
n=100   count=14   7*density=0.980000
n=1,000   c=124   7*d=0.868000
n=10,000   c=1476   7*d=1.033200
n=100,000   c=14,462   7*d=1.012340
n=1,000,000   c=143,021   7*d=1.001147
n=10,000,000   c=1,429,300   7*d=1.000510
n=100,000,000   c=14,282,517   7*d=0.999776

Comment: More figures:
n=1,000,000,000   c=142,848,630   7*d=0.999940
n=10,000,000,000   c=1,428,508,672   7*d=0.999956

So, after 10 billion numbers, it looks like it might be asymptotic to 1 in 7 are divisible by 7.
I suppose I shouldn't be surprised.